# Clear the lookAt for a figure

Tags: c++, algorithm, opengl, 3d

In my program, I have a rectangle figure on the screen for which I changed the orientation using `gluLookAt` and it always keeps on looking at the center of the window. 
In the `draw` function that is called continuously in the application, I have some states in the program.

```
    draw function
{
    //if condition 1
    gluLookAt(0,0,0); //look At the origin of the window.
    //if condition 2
    glTranslatef(20, 10, 10);//go to some point and STOP looking At 0,0,0
    //if condition 3
    glTranslatef(point);
    glRotatef()
    glTranslate(-point)
}
```

The code runs fine for the first `if condition` and the figure keeps looking properly towards the origin. When I change the flag in my application for the second `if condition` to become true, I get the translation but my shape still keeps on looking at the origin.
How do I make this stop? I want the shape to be straight as any normal rectangle would have been drawn without the lookAt.

The figure here is not necessarily a rectangle. It might be some other shape as well

Comment: All of these matrix operations multiply with the current matrix. They don't create a new, clean matrix for you. Try putting a glLoadIdentity() at the beginning of each of your conditions.

Comment: @Aeluned : I tried adding glLoadIdentity but it acutally remove the effect of my translation, and rotaton calls in the second if condition. Is that natural or I am missing something? The translations to the final points for my shape in the second if condition don't happen now

Comment: I see no rotation calls in your second if condition (condition 2). glLoadIdentity does what is says. It loads the identity matrix into the current matrix. This is a matrix defining no transformations. There's too little code here for me to get an idea of what you're trying to do. 

I can however tell you that the solution to your problem is going to involve some combination of glLoadIdentity and glPush/Pop matrix. I suggest you look these up if you don't know what they do.

Comment: @Aeluned : The second if condition in my code looks something like this: http://pastebin.com/VBum4sPZ . The shape class that I have here continously calls the draw dunction. So, in the second if condition when I call `glLoadIdentity()`, the origin is reset to what position? Is the origin set top left somewhere and I ahev to do my translations with respect to that?

Answer (score 0):

Initialize you matrix with a call to `glLoadIdentity`(i.e. in the second `if condition` before `glTranslatef` call).
See http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glLoadIdentity.xml

> glLoadIdentity — replace the current matrix with the identity matrix

Comment: I tried adding `glLoadIdentity` but it acutally remove the effect of my translation, and rotaton calls in the second if condition. Is that natural or I am missing something? The translations to the final points for my shape in the second if condition don't happen now.

Comment: `glLoadIdentity` sets current matrix to identity - effectively "removing effects" from any transform-modifying calls(glRotate, glTranslate, glLoadMatrix, gluLookAt, gluPerspective etc) made prior to it.

Comment: The second if condition in my code looks something like this: pastebin.com/VBum4sPZ . The shape class that I have here continously calls the draw dunction. So, in the second if condition when I call glLoadIdentity(), the origin is reset to what position? Is the origin set top left somewhere and I ahev to do my translations with respect to that?

Comment: A guess - origin is reset to the center of the screen.